# Disabling paths in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to figure out how to disable the Rails magic of loading paths by default.

For example Rails has these paths.

```
Rails.config.autoload_paths
Rails.config.eager_load_paths
Rails.config.paths
```

Which will default to including the `app` directory and I don't want Rails to.

Currently I've been able to make the first two paths empty so that it doesn't include anything by default.

This is what printing out `Rails.config.paths` reveals.

```
"[[\"app\"], [\"app/assets\"], [\"app/controllers\"], [\"app/helpers\"], [\"app/models\"],
[\"app/mailers\"], [\"app/views\"], [\"lib\"], [\"lib/assets\"], [\"lib/tasks\"],
[\"config\"], [\"config/environments\"], [\"config/initializers\"], [\"config/locales\"],
[\"config/routes.rb\"], [\"db\"], [\"db/migrate\"], [\"db/seeds.rb\"], [\"vendor\"], 
[\"vendor/assets\"], [\"vendor/plugins\"], [\"config/database.yml\"],
[\"config/environment.rb\"], [\"lib/templates\"], [\"log/development.log\"], [\"public\"], 
[\"public/javascripts\"], [\"public/stylesheets\"], [\"tmp\"]]"
```

However `Rails.config.paths` seems to still load everything in `app`, `config`, etc. Does anyone know of a way to work around this? I've been looking at the source code of Rails trying to figure it out.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would one want to disable the Rails magic of loading paths by default?

Comment: I'm creating a gem based off the models and I don't want everything by default.

Comment: If you're only using models, maybe just use the ActiveRecord gem and avoid bringing in all of Rails?

Comment: @NickVeys Thanks for that! I definitely wasn't searching for the right thing. I've found some posts regarding ActiveRecord without Rails. This is what I need for gemifying just the models.